# Magento CE 1.7.0.2: some methods do not work only when the cache is enabled on footer.phtml

Tags: magento, caching, footer

Magento Cache Enabled: methods like Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage(), among others, do not work only when the cache enabled on footer.phtml

Comment: <reference name="footer">
<action method="setCacheLifetime" />
</reference>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they wont as the phtml of the footer will cache as a block.  You should either nest blocks within it in your page.xml which will not cache - such as cart_sidebar for example, or if you are targeting the home page only, then in admin go to the home page cms, go to layout updates and add the block there;

```
<reference name="footer">
<block type="your/block" name="yourblock" template="path/to/block.phtml" before="-"  />
</reference>
```